# Include OpenCV for Project in C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I feel like this should be basic, but I can't find anything for it online. I downloaded OpenCV and can't figure out how to have my projects recognize it. When I try to include it with like

```
#include <opencv2/core/version.hpp>
```

I get the error:

> "No such file or directory"

The only solution I've tried is to add /usr/include/opencv4/ to my PATH. Also, I am running ArchLinux if that is helpful to know.

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/master/db/df5/tutorial_linux_gcc_cmake.html

Comment: This is clearly duplicate of [linking opencv libraries with g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162399/linking-opencv-libraries-with-g). Please search before asking about basics

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up just moving the directory /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2 to /usr/include and that worked. Unless there are any ways to add directories to the list of directories that c++ checks when running the #include, this is the only way I've figured to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

if you have trouble with this

```
#include <opencv2/core/version.hpp>
```

You can find more detail information on "Googling".
what I have organized shown below:

1. try using `include "opencv2/core/version.hpp"` instead of it.
2. [right-click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLVNX.png), then [check-the-location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOE5M.png)
3. recheck several environment settings:

- [Additional Include Directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LgBJ.png)
- [Linker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VaHW.png)
- [Additional Dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DMuf.png)
- PATH

Answer (score 0):

Try changing these three:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
CPATH=$CPATH:/usr/include/opencv4
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64:/usr/lib
```

Comment: Hm, I'm still getting the same error after I run that command.

Comment: What are the contents of this path `/usr/include/opencv4/`?

Comment: I believe it is the base for opencv files. I.e. in opencv4 is a folder called opencv2 which contains all of the actual .hpp files.

Comment: Try this, and make sure these three paths contain OpenCV files